# start a new project in IONIC error

Tags: ionic-framework

*i want to start a new project in IONIC with this command* "**ionic start myApps tabs**" *but i get this error* : 
**[INFO] Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz) × Downloading - failed! Error: unable to verify the first certificate     at Error (native)     at TLSSocket. (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)**
please help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure that you have the latest node, cordova and ionic cli updates.
- Try to stop all server instances. I mean stop the localhost:8080 server.